# drawing simple shapes -> paint method and interface for JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, interface

I'm doing an assignment for school and I can't get my head around the logic I need to use to solve this. I hope some of you can point me in the right direction.
I have some classes to draw simple shapes:

**Class Diagram 1**
[image: Class Diagram 1]

**Extended Class Diagram**
[image: Extended Class Diagram]

According to the assignment every deferred class under `DrawingItem` needs a `paint()` method to be able to paint the particular (`Oval`, `Spline` etc..) independent from `GraphicsContext`. For `Oval`, my guess is this method would be something like:

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
     g.setColor(super.getColor());
     g.drawOval(
        (int) dw.getAnchor().getX(), (int) dw.getAnchor().getY(), 
        (int)this.width, (int)this.height
     );`
}
```

Extended class diagram shows an interface `IPaintable` which I have created with a method for every shape. The JavaFX side (`DrawingTool`) implements this interface and all of its methods. These methods want the shape object as argument. I use these methods to draw the shapes in javaFX, again the oval example:

```
strokeOval(
    oval.getHeight(), oval.getWidth(), oval.getAnchor().getX(), oval.getAnchor().getY()
);
```

The main questions I have are these:

1. Am I going in the right direction with the `paint()` methods in the shape subclasses and if so how do I call them from the JavaFX side?
2. How can I "implement" the `paint(paintable:IPaintable)` method in the `Drawing` and `DrawingItem` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 design patterns easily identifiable in the class diagrams:

The `IPaintable` is supposed to be a wrapper(Facade) for the GUI drawing operations allowing you to use the classes in *Class Diagram 1* independent from the GUI library used. You should only use the methods provided by `IPaintable` in the `paint` methods.

The classes in *Class Diagram 1* are the *command* part of the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern); `DrawingTool` is the *invoker*/*client* and `IPaintable` is the *receiver*.

---

The `DrawingTool` class should contain code like this:

```
IPaintable paintable = new JavaFXPaintable(canvas.getGraphicsContext());
```

and use it like this, if the drawing needs to be redrawn:

```
drawing.paint(paintable);
```

#### Implementing the `paint` methods

Since a `Oval` can be drawn using `IPaintable`'s methods, it should implement `paint` like this:

```
public void paint(IPaintable paintable) {
    paintable.setColor(color);
    paintable.paintOval(this);
}
```

`Polygon` would use the `paintLine` methods of the `IPaintable` passed to it's `paint` method for drawing itself, `Drawing.paint` would clear the `IPaintable` and draw all it's `items` ect.

In `JavaFxPaintable` the `paintOval` method would be implemented like this:

```
public void paintOval(Oval oval) {
    Point anchor = oval.getAnchor();
    graphics.strokeOval(anchor.getX(), anchor.getY(), oval.getWidth(), oval.getHeight());
}
```

You may need to modify this a bit, if `anchor` denotes the top-left instead of the the center.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks fabian, pointing me in this direction realy helped a lot (as cleaning up my post for readability did too).
Now I have implemented these pointers and they seem to work. With the draw() method in Drawingtool I call the paint(IPaintable paintable) method in the Drawing class, which loops through the list of drawingitems in this class like so:

```
public void paint(IPaintable paintable){
        for (DrawingItem test : drawingitems){
            if (test instanceof Oval){
                paintable.paintOval((Oval) paintable);
                }  else if (test instanceof Image){
                    paintable.paintImage((Image) paintable);
```

This should paint the shapes and seem to work. The last part is adding them to the canvas initialized in the DrawingTool class. I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I've tried to add them while going through the list with drawing items but this does not seem to work (or I'm handling it wrong).